# Azure Data Factory vs App Insight

Tags: azure, factory, azure-application-insights

i need to push Azure data factory logs to App Insight. if anyone know , could you please let me know the steps that i need to follow.

Thanks
Dinusha

Answer (score 1):

**`No`**, Currently, Data Factory workflows are not hooked up with Azure Application Insights

Comment: Thanks for your Answer

Comment: how about now? what are people using for app insights wiwth dfac? is there a different solution?